# Can I share my computers wireless internet connection with my DVR?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a wireless modem for my home network. Can I use this Internet connection for the DVR Internet connection, without buying an adapter? My OS is Windows XP Pro.

Comment: is your computer close to your DVR? Because then you should change your question into: How can I let my DVR share my computer's wireless connection?

Comment: You might want to say what make/model your DVR is. Also, is the DVR close enough to the router or computer that you could run a cable to it?

Comment: Seems I've misplaced my dvr manual, but it is Directv HD only about 6 months old. The wirless modem is VisioNet M505. Yes, I do have the dvr cabled to a hub for my network. I have also attached the cat5 directly to the modem with the same result, networked with no internet connection. I'm assuming that an adapter would allow me to put in the key number for the modem. But I was wondering if I could get an internet connection just by having it networked.

Comment: According to the [documentation for your modem](http://www.blackfoot.com/pdf/faq-pro/VisionNet_M505_User_Manual.pdf), you should be able to plug your DVR into one of the four ports on it and get Internet access.  If that's not working, there is something wrong with your modem or your DVR.  Try disconnecting from the wireless and plugging your computer in via Ethernet and see if you get Internet access.  That will isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [DirecTV support site](http://support.directv.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2807/kw/internet). A wireless connection requires a kit, but a cabled connection doesn't. Did you go into the system setup as indicated in the demo?

Comment: Yes, I've tried the wired option on the dvr system setup with no success. I guess now my question is, if I have a wireless modem is the wired option out for me?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that offered help. About midnight I finally got an internet connection.  The living room is networked and that is where I attached the cat 5 from the dvr.  Made sure the connection was good by connecting the laptop. It was networked and had internet connection.  Finally,I just happen to have a 50 ft. cat 5, strung it thru the house and just barely attached it to the modem. And in an instant I had internet. Still can't figure out why no connection using the house network. Again thanks
Dixie